# Notification : my Update receiver not call

Tags: android

I new for the notification.I don't find any help for this please help me.Thank you in advance.I have to show notification in android app but It does not get call to my broadcast receiver though I added permission in manifest

```
<Service android:name="com.example.tajgroup.newsapplication.service.NotificationService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <receiver android:name=".reciever.UpdateReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.com.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
            /></receiver>




and my NotificationService and UpdateReciever are



public class UpdateReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
        NetworkInfo networkInfo;
        String dateString;

        public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        public static int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;

        static Intent serviceintent;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                if (!isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                        // Notification(context, "Wifi Connection Off");

                } else {

                        serviceintent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
                        context.startService(serviceintent);
                        context.stopService(serviceintent);

                }
        }

        // Check for network availability
        private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                        .getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return activeNetworkInfo != null;
        }

}






public class NotificationService extends Service {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    NotificationService notification;
    String dateString,Name;
    Categories categories;

    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;
    private Context _context;
    long count, cnt, date1;
    int flag = 0;
    public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        /*Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();*/

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Stared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        date1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateString = sdf.format(date1);
        System.out.println("Ntification item1 = " + dateString);
        //dateString="07/11/2014";
        notification();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private void notification(){

        final RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Config.url)
                .build();

        MainActivityInterface api = adapter.create(MainActivityInterface.class);

        api.Test(
                new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                        BufferedReader reader = null;
                        String message = "";
                        String output = "";

                        try {
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));
                            output = reader.readLine();
                            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(output);

                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tokener);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("story");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                int id = jsonObj.getInt("id");
                                String title = jsonObj.getString("title");
                                String content = jsonObj.getString("content");
                                String picture = jsonObj.getString("picture");
                                String saved_file_name = jsonObj.getString("saved_file_name");
                                String status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                                String start_date = jsonObj.getString("start_date");
                                String end_date = jsonObj.getString("end_date");
                                String created_at = jsonObj.getString("created_at");
                                String updated_at = jsonObj.getString("updated_at");

                                categories = new Categories(id,title,content,picture,saved_file_name,status,start_date,end_date,created_at,updated_at);

                                   String[] items = categories.getUpdated_at().split(" ");
                                   String date1, time;
                                   date1 = items[0];
                                   time = items[1];
                                   System.out.println("item = " + updated_at);
                                System.out.println("noti item1 = " + date1);

                                if(date1.equals(dateString)) {
                                   notification = new NotificationService();
                                   Name = categories.getTitle();
                                   a.add("\n" + Name);
                               }
                            }

                            notification.Notification(NotificationService.this," \n" + a);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(NotificationService.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        );
    }

    void Notification(Context context, String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Set Notification Title
        String strtitle = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                // Set Icon
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pen_50px)
                // Set Ticker Message
                .setTicker(message)
                // LED
                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)

                // Set Title
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                // Set Text
                .setContentText(message)
                // Add an Action Button below Notification
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_more, "Click to Check", pIntent)
                // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                // Dismiss Notification
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Create Notification Manager
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It may need SelfCheckPermission. What API level are you working on?

Comment: how will it use self check permission sir

Comment: Just google it. If you are using API 24 or above, you need to grant user for permission. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thank you sir, for your valuable responce

Comment: Avoid asking question in answer. Also show your work and research when you answer

Comment: Could somebody grants me. I need some points to remove restriction from my account. @Priyanka. Could mark as a useful answer. Thanks.